# What width of wire for 24V DC LED driver?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, cables

I bought a 24V/25W LED driver from a local shop and the sales assistant sold me a short length of **20AWG** control wire to go with it.

In order to buy more wire (elsewhere) I looked up the UK (mm2) equivalent and found it to be 0.5mm2, however I notice that the driver's output terminals have written on them `Sec:24VDC 0.75`. Is "0.75" a wire gauge recommendation? Should I be using 0.75 wire rather than 0.5?

Comment: I think the 0.75 indicates the driver can supply up to 0.75 amps at 24VDC on the secondary (that is, on the output).

Answer (score 3):

20 AWG is rated for 5 amps, so it's good for taking any strip as far as you ought to.

I prefer 22 AWG or 0.25 mm<sup>2</sup>, and stranded wire.  The reason is, if the wires are any thicker, they will tend to "wag the dog", pulling the LED strip out of shape/position and potentially tearing off the solder pad.

The "0.75" on the output terminals is surely not a wire gauge recommendation, but **read the data sheet** to be sure.  Remember when installing mains equipment (and a driver is that), you must install in accordance with the instructions and labeling.  That indicates the conditions under which the item was certified as safe by UL, CSA, ETL, BSI, TUV -- whichever lab did the safety cert on it.  Note that CE is not a testing lab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The driver's instructions don't mention wire gauge or amperage. I looked for a data sheet on the manufacturer's site and that is equally as brief. This is the product: [AU-LED2524CV](https://auroralighting.com/gb/trade/ProductDetail/AU-LED2524CV)

Comment: At **most**, a 24V 25W driver would put out 1.04 Amps - P=IV, P/V=I and I suspect the comment that 0.75 is an amperage means that they have advertised the input power, so it's really a *not terribly efficient* 18W (output) driver.